# Use Logistic Regression for Tweets Topic Classification

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, logistic-regression, text-classification

I have a problem regarding use of Logistic Regression. I'm currently making a Tweets Topic Classification in Python. 
so far I'm able to read the train data from MySQL table using pandas, clean the train tweets using NLTK and create feature vectors using CountVectorizer. 
here's the code below..

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import *
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

#connect to database and get the training data
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost:3306/machinelearning')
tweet = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT label, tweets FROM tweetstable', engine, index_col='label')

#TEXT PREPROCESSING (REMOVE HTML MARKUP, REMOVE PUNCTUATION, TOKENIZING, REMOVE STOP WORDS, STEMMING)

def preprocessing(pptweets):
    pptweets = pptweets.lower()
    urlrtweets = re.sub(r'https:.*$', ":", pptweets)
    rpptweets = urlrtweets.replace("_", " ")
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(rpptweets)
    filteredwords = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
    stweets = [stemmer.stem(tokens) for tokens in filteredwords]
    return " ".join(stweets)

#initialize an empty list to hold the clean reviews
cleantweets = []

#loop over each review, create an index i that goes from 0 to the length of tweets list
for i in range(0, len(tweet["tweets"])):
    cleantweets.append(preprocessing(tweet["tweets"][i]))

#initialize the "CountVectorizer" object, which is scikit-learn's BoW tools
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer="word",
                             tokenizer=None,
                             preprocessor=None,
                             stop_words=None,
                             max_features=5000)

#fit_transform() does two functions: First, it fits the model
#and learns the vocabulary; second, it transforms our training data
#into feature vectors. the input to fit_transform should be a list of strings
traindatafeatures = vectorizer.fit_transform(cleantweets)

#Numpy arrays are easy to work with, so convert the result to an array
traindatafeatures = traindatafeatures.toarray()
```

the problem I'm facing right now is.. I don't know how to use Logistic Regression to learn from the train data. here's the code I use to fit the train data into Logistic Regression classifier.

```
#train the model
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(traindatafeatures, tweet["label"])

#check trained model intercept

print(logmodel.intercept_)
#check trained model coefficients
print(logmodel.coef_)
```

I pass the traindatafeatures as the input X and tweet["label"] as the label/class Y for each tweet to Logistic Regression classifier so it can learn from it but when I run the full code I get error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Indra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1945, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'label'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Indra/PycharmProjects/TextClassifier/textclassifier.py", line 52, in <module>
    logmodel.fit(traindatafeatures, tweet["label"])
  File "C:\Users\Indra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\Indra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\Indra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\Indra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\Indra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'label'
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? :( I've been searching for tutorials but I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: You are setting the label as an index (as part of the pd.read_sql_query), therefore it is no longer available as column. Use tweet.index to get the label column, or remove the index_col argument.

Comment: I removed the index_col argument and was able to run the program. What I want to ask now is what do you mean by use tweet.index? Can you show how to do it?

Comment: He means that, in case you want to keep `label` as `index` (which is the result of using the `index_col` keyword with `read_sql`, then you could use `tweet.index` instead of `tweet['label']` with `.fit()`. Since you dropped `index_col`, the former is no longer necessary.

Comment: ah I understand now. thanks @Stefan for the help :)

Comment: thanks @AlexanderBauer for the help :)